# Proof of associativity of convolution

Tags: calculus, convolution

I intend to prove the associativity of convolution but failed after several trials, i.e.
$(f \ast g) \ast h = f \ast (g \ast h)$
where $(f \ast g)(t) = \int^{t}_{0}f(s)g(t-s)ds $

There are a number of proves considering $(f \ast g)(t) = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}f(s)g(t-s)ds $. Those did not help since I have a different definition.

Would anyone be able to show the proof here?

Thanks.

Comment: Consider your functions $f(s), g(s), h(s)$ to take value $0$ if $s \notin [0, t]$. This makes the case with integration on $[0, t]$ equivalent to the case with integration on $(-\infty, \infty)$.

Comment: I would like to insist on doing it by change of integration variables or other means, instead of changing the integration domain to $(-\infty, \infty)$.

Comment: Have you tried using Fubini's theorem (i.e. change the order of integration)? Usually this does the magic whenver repeated integral is involved.

Comment: I tried, but never succeed in arranging both sides in the same form.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Using the following convolution of $f$ and $g$
\begin{align*}
(f\star g)(t)=\int_0^tf(s)g(t-s)ds
\end{align*}

> we obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{((f\star g)\star h)(t)}&=\int_0^t(f\star g)(s)h(t-s)\,ds\\
> &=\int_{s=0}^t\left(\int_{u=0}^sf(u)g(s-u)\,du\right)h(t-s)\,ds\\
> &=\int\!\!\!\int_{0\leq u \leq s\leq t}f(u)g(s-u)h(t-s)\,du\,ds\\
> &=\int_{u=0}^t\int_{s=u}^tf(u)g(s-u)h(t-s)\,ds\,du\\
> &=\int_{u=0}^tf(u)\left(\int_{s=0}^{t-u}g(s)h(t-u-s)\,ds\right)\,du\\
> &=\int_{u=0}^tf(u)(g\star h)(t-u)\,du\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=(f\star (g\star h))(t)}
> \end{align*}

**Note:** This corresponds to the *discrete* case which could be somewhat easier to follow.
\begin{align*}
(f\star g)(n)=\sum_{k=0}^nf(k)g(n-k)
\end{align*}

Here we get

\begin{align*}
((f\star g)\star h)(n)&=\sum_{k=0}^n(f\star g)(k)h(n-k)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\sum_{l=0}^kf(l)g(k-l)\right)h(n-k)\\
&=\sum_{0\leq l \leq k \leq n}f(l)g(k-l)h(n-k)\\
&=\sum_{l=0}^n\sum_{k=l}^nf(l)g(k-l)h(n-k)\\
&=\sum_{l=0}^nf(l)\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-l}g(k)h(n-k-l)\right)\\
&=\sum_{l=0}^nf(l)(g\star h)(n-l)\\
&=(f\star(g\star h))(n)
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks Markus. The solution is very neat and tidy. I think I worked out the wrong integral limit after exchanging the integration order.

Comment: @Simon: You're welcome! :-)

Comment: @MarkusScheuer I started from  ${(f\star (g\star h))(t)} $ and got a similar result. However, I cannot be sure that this is mathematically correct. Is it possible to do it that way? I looked at many proofs on the net and they always start from $ {((f\star g)\star h)(t)}$ not the other way around.

Comment: @Vesnog: It is just a matter of convenience from which side one might start. Recall that equality is an equivalence relation, which is in particular a symmetrical relation. You might also read the equality chain from my answer from the right-hand side to the left.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why the exchange of the integral is justified here?

Comment: @TrashFailure: Here it is implicitly assumed that the exchange of integrals is admissible.

Comment: how did u swap ds and dU?

Comment: @JosephRock: I've rewritten the index region somewhat more conveniently to better see the triangle area.